# I don't know how to access my created file

Tags: command-line, 18.04, wireless, files, find

I'm trying to connect my home wifi to my machine with wpa_supplicant but don't know the path to the file with SSID and passphrase. If I do `ls -a -1 | less` from my user account I can see it in the list, but I don't know what the path is to move it. I'm new to this OS.

Ubuntu Server 18.04

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UTP cable running and you have internet connection you can install midnight commander and turn on the light.

```
sudo apt install mc
```

Then start mc with:

```
mc
```

It has a build in viewer and editor too and much more.
You will be able to find and view your file with ease.